# Get model which has all specific related models

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, lumen, eloquent-relationship

I have no idea how to solve my problem.

I have `Model1` with relation:

```
class Model1 extends BaseModel
{
    public function details(): BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(
            Detail::class,
            'model1_details',
            'model1_id',
            'detail_id',
        );
    }
}
```

`model1_details` is my pivot table.

Also I have array of details ids like `[1, 2, 3]`.
I need to fetch `Model1` that belongs to ALL `Detail` with given ids.

I need to do this inside my filter.
That's what I have inside my controller:

```
$builder = Model1::filter(new ModelListFilter($request));
```

and inside ModelListFilter:

```
protected function filter(): Builder
    {
        $request = $this->request;

        $request->whenFilled('details', function ($query) {
            //
        });

        return $this->builder;
    }
```

I've tried:

```
$request->whenFilled('details', function ($query) {
            foreach($query as $detailId) {
                $this->builder->whereHas('details', function (Builder $innerQuery) use ($detailId) {
                    $innerQuery->where('detail_id',  $detailId);
                });
            }
        });
```

But it returns all models Model1 even without any details.

**UPD**

So the problem wasn't there =) `'details'` just wasn't filled in my Request.
also my `$query` was a string, not array, so I called json_decode on it.

Code above retrieves Models belonging to detail with id=1 AND to detail with id=2 and so on.

But I think there might be better solution so I'll leave this question open

**UPD 2**

also changed this

```
$innerQuery->where('detail_id',  $detailId);
```

to this

```
$innerQuery->where('id',  $detailId);
```

so here is needed to pass columns we have in 'details' table, not columns from pivot table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution to my problem [here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/wherehas-where-multiple-must-contain?page=1&replyId=191194). So it seems like there is no better solution(

Answer (score 0):

I can't see where you load the relationship with details. Not sure if you're missing a file, but in case you're not, load the relationship in the first part of the query with the [eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) `with` method:

```
$builder = Model1::with('details')->filter(new ModelListFilter($request));
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion , but It did not help. 
Also as I understand from laravel documentation is that we don't need 'with' method to use 'whereHas' example from laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships 
$posts = Post::whereHas('comments', function (Builder $query) { $query->where('content', 'like', 'code%'); })->get();

Comment: @Natali Not really. WhereHas just validates the existence of the related record but doesn't retrieve it

Comment: Okay, but I don't need to retrieve related model, just check if Model1 has related models with specific ids

Comment: Yes. My bad. I re-read the question. Can you get the compiled query of this issue?

Comment: I understood where was my problem and updated question, thank you again

Comment: Now you can try the second answer (the whereIn one)

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there but you still missing two things,

#### WhereIn list

to get model `whereHas` their details ids in a list you need to use `WhereIn` instead of looping the query

#### Eager load the details relationship

to get the details list with each model you have to use the `with` keyword to eager load the relationship

### Solution

```
// builder
$builder = Model1::with('details')->filter(new ModelListFilter($request));

// filter
$request->whenFilled('details', function (array $details) {
       $this->builder->whereHas('details', function (Builder 
            $innerQuery) use ($details) {
                    $innerQuery->whereIn('detail_id',  $details);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thank you! But it's opposite solution. Using this code I get Models belonging to detail with id=1 OR id=2 OR id=3. What I need is Model belonging to tag with id=1 AND to tag with id=2 AND...